# Getting access key for connected OIDC provider from AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have added a OIDC provider to my user pool on AWS by [following the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/external-identity-providers.html).

The users are now able to create their accounts by using the SSO. How can I access the access_token / refresh_token returned by the OIDC provider so I can use them in my backend?

For example:
If the user connects through Facebook, how can I get their access_token on the backend to gather more data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

### Create a custom attribute in a user pool

Follow these steps to create a custom attribute in your user pool:

1. Open the new Amazon Cognito console, and then choose the Sign-up Experience tab in your user pool.
2. Under the Custom Attributes section, select the Add custom attributes button.
3. To create a custom attribute for an access token, enter the following values, and then save the changes.

**Name:** access_token
**Type:** String
**Max:** 2,048
**Mutable:** Select this check box

4. To create a custom attribute for an ID token, enter the following values, and then save the changes.

**Name:** id_token
**Type:** String
**Max:** 2,048
**Mutable:** Select this check box

### Configure attribute mapping between Amazon Cognito and your IdP

Follow these steps to configure attribute mapping to IdP attributes:

1. Open the new Amazon Cognito console, and then choose the Sign-in Experience tab in your user pool.
2. Under the Federated Identity Provider sign-in section, select your IdP from the list.
3. Choose the Edit option near the Identity provider information section. Make sure that the following scopes are present in the Authorized scopes section:

Facebook example scopes: public_profile, email
Google example scopes: profile email openid
Login with Amazon example scopes: profile postal_code
Sign in with Apple example scopes: email name
All other OIDC providers example scopes: profile email openid
4.    Go one step back to the Identity provider page. Choose Edit near the Attribute mapping section.

5. From the User pool attribute column, select the custom attribute that you created in the beginning.
6. From the OpenID Connect attribute column, select access_token or id_token, depending on the type of token to be mapped. Then, save your changes.

Example results of configuring attribute mapping:

**User pool attribute:** custom: id_token
**OpenID Connect attribute:** id_token

**User pool attribute: custom:** access_token
**OpenID Connect attribute:** access_token

Turn on attribute read and write permissions in your Amazon Cognito app client
When a user signs in to the application, Amazon Cognito updates the mapped attributes. For Amazon Cognito to update the mapped user pool attributes, the mapped attributes must be writable in your application's app client settings. For Amazon Cognito to update the user's ID token, the attributes must be readable in your application's app client settings.

1. Open the new Amazon Cognito console, and then choose the App integration tab in your user pool.
2. Select your app client from the list of app clients.
3. In the Attribute read and write permissions section, choose Edit.
4. On the Edit attribute read and write permissions page, select the read and write check boxes for your custom attributes.
5. Save the changes.

Repeat these steps for each app client that uses the custom attribute.

Source:
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-tokens-issued-by-idp